# Visual Studio - Possible to create support for other languages?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

Is it possible through their add-ins to add support to other languages that c# or vb.net? I mean, like have full control of the IDE, debugging included.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, using [Visual Studio Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx).

"For an end-to-end sample of a language project system with debugging support, see the [IronPython](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165436.aspx) sample."

Comment: Are there any good books about it? I've read there is one with that name - Visual Studio Extensibility, but it  seems to have aweful reviews.

Answer (score 2):

Then is a framework called the [Irony project](http://irony.codeplex.com/) on codeplex to help with the creation of new language support.